# How to hide a particular image in HTML

Tags: html

I am using a og:image meta property to define an image so whenever I shared my webpage in WhatsApp or Facebook, that image will be shown as a thumbnail.

But all my pages had a specific image. I want to show these images as a thumbnail. So I removed the meta tag.

`<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.website.com/download.png">`

But all my pages have 2 images. One is on top and the other is on the footer. As the footer image is big, whenever I shared my page, only the footer image is shown as a thumbnail. I want to show the top image to be a thumbnail. So how to hide the footer image?

Comment: Without an `og:image` tag, sites like Facebook will make a guess. Sometimes it'll be wrong. If you want to pick the image, set an `og:image` tag. That's what it's there for. You can have a different one for each page, if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Sharing Debugger to see the information that is used when your website content is shared on Facebook, Messenger and other places.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

And it will also displays the missing properties.

Open Graph Object Debugger will also help you 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

If you want to know more about OGP you can visit

http://ogp.me/